# MapReduce Old API - Passing Command Line Argument to Map

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am coding a MapReduce job for finding the occurrence of a search string (passed through Command Line argument) in an input file stored in HDFS using old API.

Below is my Driver class -

```
public class StringSearchDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JobConf jc = new JobConf(StringSearchDriver.class);
        jc.set("SearchWord", args[2]);
        jc.setJobName("String Search");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(jc, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jc, new Path(args[1]));
        jc.setMapperClass(StringSearchMap.class);
        jc.setReducerClass(StringSearchReduce.class);
        jc.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        jc.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        JobClient.runJob(jc);
    }
}
```

Below is my Mapper Class -

```
public class StringSearchMap extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    String searchWord;

    public void configure(JobConf jc)
    {
        searchWord = jc.get("SearchWord");

    }



    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,  
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> out, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException
    {
        String[] input = value.toString().split("");

        for(String word:input)
        {
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord))
                out.collect(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }

}
```

On running the job (command line string passed is "hi"), I am getting the below error -

```
14/09/21 22:35:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409212134_0005_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ClassCastException: interface javax.xml.soap.Text
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `ClassCastException: interface javax.xml.soap.Text` looks like you auto-imported the wrong Text class in your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You auto imported the wrong import.
Instead of **import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text** you **import javax.xml.soap.Text**

You can find a sample wrong import in this [blog](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/wrong-import-statements-in-hadoop.html).

One point , It is better to adopt **New API**

**EDIT**

I used New Api

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

/**
 * @author Unmesha sreeveni
 * @Date 23 sep 2014
 */
public class StringSearchDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static class Map extends
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            String line = value.toString();
            String searchString = conf.get("word");
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if(token.equals(searchString)){
                    word.set(token);
                    context.write(word, one);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends
    Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new StringSearchDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);

    }
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out
            .printf("Usage: Search String <input dir> <output dir> <search word> \n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String source = args[0];
        String dest = args[1];
        String searchword = args[2];
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("word", searchword);
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Search String");
        job.setJarByClass(StringSearchDriver.class);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path in =new Path(source);
        Path out =new Path(dest);
        if (fs.exists(out)) {
            fs.delete(out, true);
        }

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
        boolean sucess = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return (sucess ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: Thanks SreeVeni. I had not realized that the wrong package had got imported on auto-import. I corrected the package and the job ran successfully without any error. Now, the issue is that I am not getting the desired output. I passed "hi" as the search word and my sample files on HDFS contain this term. Still the output file generated after running the job is empty. Does the logic seem incorrect?

Comment: This is good with respect to the new API. But I am supposed to code it using the older API.

Comment: Try changing the code from new to old. same logic can be used.let me know if u are not able to do

Answer (score 0):

For Text;  required hadoop package is **org.apache.hadoop.io.**.
**Check your packages**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
```